# I'm getting an "Unknown build error" message, but cannot find out why

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a WPF app. I've been working on this app for several weeks. Now, all of a sudden, I can no longer compile it, debug it, run it, etc. When I try to I keep getting this error:

Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Src\LRAT...\LRAT\LRAT\obj\Debug\LRAT.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Well, certainly the .exe isn't there. But that's the whole point of building it, so it WILL be there. I've done a Get Latest, but it makes no difference whatsoever. I've cleaned my solution, gotten into and out of Visual Studio, rebooted my machine. Nothing helps. And what's really weird is my other team mates are able to compile it fine. So, what gives??

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Check your project references.  It sounds like you somehow managed to get your assembly to reference itself

Comment: Try creating a new project and re-adding all the source again?

Comment: Do you have pending changes?

Comment: I have no pending changes,

Comment: Assuming you've not got untracked changes, nuke your repo and pull it down again.

Comment: One of my colleagues suggested I add the System.Web assembly to this project. I did. I tried compiling it again, but that failed (same error). So then I undid that change (that was the only change) and now it compiles. I don't get this at all. I had no pending changes. I was up to date with what's in TFS, etc.